# How to fix method and function for objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, methods

I'm new to Javascript and this is my first time posting on StackOverflow. I've been stuck on a problem for around a week or so, and was wondering if anyone here might be able to help. We were supposed to create an assortment methods of an array & 2 functions. I've gotten stuck on these:

- `hasMoreOscarsThan`
  This method accepts one actor object as a parameter and returns true if the actor has more Oscars than the one that is passed as a parameter and false otherwise.
- `getAverageAge`
  This function returns the average age of all the actors in the array.

DECLARING MAIN FUNCTION & ARRAY

```
function famousPerson(name, age, oscars) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.oscars = oscars;
    this.hello = function () {
        console.log("Hello, my name is " + this.name + ".");
    };
    this.hasMoreOscarsThan = function (x) {
        if ( == famousPerson.oscars && this.oscars > famousPerson.oscars) {
            return this.name;
        } else {
            return "False!";
        }
    };
};
```

DECLARING OBJECTS IN ARRAY

```
var actors = [];
actors[0] = new famousPerson("Leonardo DiCaprio", 41, 1);
actors[1] = new famousPerson("Jennifer Lawrence", 25, 1);
actors[2] = new famousPerson("Samuel L. Jackson", 67, 0);
actors[3] = new famousPerson("Meryl Streep", 66, 3);
actors[4] = new famousPerson("John Cho", 43, 0);
```

These are the methods & functions I wrote:

```
// hasMoreOscarsThan method
actors.forEach(function (name.famousPerson); {
    // I put compare argument 2 and print result to console
    console.log(name.famousPerson.hasMoreOscarsThan(famousPerson.name));
});

// FUNCTIONS TO CALL
// getAverageAge function
var getAverageAge = (
    actors[0].age + actors[1].age + actors[2].age + actors[3].age + actors[4].age
) / actors.length;
```

For hasMoreOscars than, the input should be the name of another famousPerson. I was able to test the number of oscars against an integer like 2, but that's not what the question is asking...

getAverageAge should be a function. I have previously logged the sum to the console directly but there should be a more efficient way.

Many thanks, everyone!

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hasMoreOscarsThan**

you're passing x into the function but not actually using it. See below I changed x for otherPerson... and as per the question should return true, not the actors name.

```
function famousPerson(name, age, oscars) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.oscars = oscars;
    this.hello = function() {
        console.log("Hello, my name is " + this.name + ".");
    };
    this.hasMoreOscarsThan = function(otherPerson) {
        if (this.oscars > otherPerson.oscars) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
};
```

**average age**

heres a function to get the average age of the array of actors. you can see how it works, firstly it uses map to create an array of the actors ages, then i use a function called `sumarr` which i have also defined below which gives you the sum of an array of numbers, then obviously that is divided by its length to get the average.

```
function av_age(actors){
    var ages = actors.map(function(el){return el.age})
    var average = sumarr(ages)/actors.length
    return average
}

function sumarr(arr){
    return arr.reduce(function(tot, el){return tot+el});
}
```

or (all in one function)

```
function getAverageAge(actors){
    var sumOfAges= actors.reduce(function(tot, el){return tot+el.age},0)
    var average=sumOfAges / actors.length
    return average
}
```

Comment: Hi - sorry that it's taken so long for me to respond to you! Thank you!
So if I were writing a function to sum up the ages, it would be something closer to: 
    function getAverageAge(actors) {
    return actors.reduce(sum, 0);}

Comment: *updated*- if you wanted to add up all the actors ages with no helper functions like my 'sumarr' then you'd write - 'actors.reduce(function(tot, el){return tot+el.age},0)'. In this el is the actor and 0 is the starting number. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a

Comment: \ tot, el \ - in writing those were you shorthand 'total' and what else? sum and value? Also, what's the reason for noting \ ,0 \ ? - I saw that in https://developer.mozilla.org but don't get the reason, exactly. Sorry!

Comment: 'tot' and 'el' could be called anything. For me they represent total and element. So in the reduce function - the running total and then the current element. The 0 tells the reduce function that the initial value for the total is 0. Try using different values and see how it effects the outcome. You should really look into how the reduce function works as per the link and also generally how functions work if you are struggling with some of these concepts

Comment: did this help or answer your question? if it did then please remember to accept the answer with the tick.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
// It is good pracitece to use capital letter on constructor functions to remind users of your code 
// to use the NEW operator when creating instances of the object.
function FamousPerson(name, age, oscars) {
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.oscars = oscars;
this.hello = function() {
console.log("Hello, my name is " + this.name + ".");
};
this.hasMoreOscarsThan = function(otherFamousPerson) {
  // you pass a FamousPerson object as a parameter (named otherFamousPerson) and then
  // compare the oscar property of the otherFamousPerson parameter against the oscar property of this object.
  if (this.oscars > otherFamousPerson.oscars) {
      return this.name;
  } else {
      return "False!";
  }
};

};

// DECLARING OBJECTS IN ARRAY

var actors = [];
actors[0] = new FamousPerson("Leonardo DiCaprio", 41, 1);
actors[1] = new FamousPerson("Jennifer Lawrence", 25, 1);
actors[2] = new FamousPerson("Samuel L. Jackson", 67, 0);
actors[3] = new FamousPerson("Meryl Streep", 66, 3);
actors[4] = new FamousPerson("John Cho", 43, 0);

// Compare the oscars of 2 FamousPerson objects:
console.log(actors[3].hasMoreOscarsThan(actors[1]));

// Compute the average age of all FamousPerson objects in the actors array:
averageAge = actors.reduce(function(sum,actor){
  return sum+actor.age;
},0)/actors.length;

console.log(averageAge);
```

you can find more info about the Array.prototype.reduce method here on MDN:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a